# Set of linear equations

Tags: matrix, matlab

I have \$ N^2 \$ matrices. Each one is a \$ 3 \times 3 \$ matrix. I want to concatenation them to a \$ 3N \times 3N \$ matrix. I know that the big matrix is symmetric. Evaluation of whole \$ 3 \times 3 \$ matrices are time consuming so I want to speed up my program.

Do you have any suggestion to speed it up?

```
clc 
load rv
load a                          %#  Nx3 matrix [x1 y1 z1;x2 y2 z2;... ].
                                %#  vectors construct a sphere
L=(301:500)*1e-9;  K=2*pi./L;   %# 1x200 array 
%# some constants =========================================================
I=eye(3);
e0=1;
[npoints,ndims]=size(rv);  
N=npoints;
d0=(4*pi/(3*N))^(1/3)*5e-9;
V=N*d0^3; aeq=(3*V/(4*pi))^(1/3);       
E0y=ones(N,1);
E0z=E0y;
Cext=zeros(1,length(L));
Qext=zeros(1,length(L));
A=zeros(3,3,N^2);
% =================================
r=sqrt(sum(rv,2).^2);           %# [Nx1] lengrh of each rv vector
for i=1:N
    for j=1:N
        dx(i,j)=rv(i,1)-rv(j,1); %# The x component of distances between each 2 point [NxN]
        dy(i,j)=rv(i,2)-rv(j,2); %# The y component of distances between each 2 point [NxN]
        dz(i,j)=rv(i,3)-rv(j,3); %# The z component of distances between each 2 point [NxN]
    end
end
dv=cat(3,dx,dy,dz);  %# d is the distance between each 2 point (a 3D matrix) [NxNx3]
d=sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2+dz.^2);                     %# length of each dv vector
nx=dv(:,:,1)./d; ny=dv(:,:,2)./d; nz=dv(:,:,3)./d;
n=cat(3,nx,ny,nz);                              %# Unit vectors for points that construct my sphere


for s=1:length(L)
   E0x=exp(1i*K(s)*rv(:,1))'; % ' #closing the quote for syntax highlighting
   % 1x200 array  in direction of x(in Cartesian coordinate system)
   % Main Loop    =================================================
   p=1;                                                        
   for i=1:N                                                  
       for j=1:N                                              
           if i==j                                           
               A(:,:,p)=a(s)*eye(3);           %# 3x3 , a is a 1x200 constant array                        
               p=p+1;                          %# p is only a counter              
           else                                                
           A(:,:,p)=-exp(1i*K(s)*d(i,j))/d(i,j)*(-K(s)^2*([nx(i,j);ny(i,j);nz(i,j)]... 
               *[nx(i,j) ny(i,j) nz(i,j)]-I)+(1/d(i,j)^2-1i*K(s)/d(i,j))...             
               *(3*[nx(i,j);ny(i,j);nz(i,j)]*[nx(i,j) ny(i,j) nz(i,j)]-I));             
           p=p+1;          
           end                                             
       end                                                 
   end                                                     

%===============================================================
B = reshape(permute(reshape(A,3,3*N,[]),[2 1 3]),3*N,[]).';    %# From :gnovice
%# concatenation of N^2 3x3 matrixes into a 3Nx3N matrix

    for i=1:N
        E00(:,i)=[E0x(i) E0y(i) E0z(i)]';
    end
    b=reshape(E00,3*N,1);
    P=inv(B)*b;
    Cext(s)=(4*pi*K(s))*imag(b'*P);
    Qext(s)=Cext(s)/(pi*aeq^2);
 end

Qmax=max(Qext); Qext=Qext/Qmax;
L=L*1e9;
plot(L,Qext,'--');figure(gcf)

%# The B matrix is symmetric(B_ij=B_ji) so I can reduce the computations
%# I think I should write sth like this
% for i=1:N                                                  
%        for j=i:N                                              
%            if i==j                                           
%                A(:,:,p)=a(s)*eye(3);           %# 3x3 , a is a 1x200 constant array                        
%                p=p+1;                          %# p is only a counter              
%            else                                                
%            A(:,:,p)=... [just same as above]             
%            p=p+1;          
%            end                                             
%        end                                                 
%    end      
% But how concatenate them like befor in order?
```

Pls get  a.mat :   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21031944/Stack/a.mat

```
     rv.mat:   http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21031944/Stack/rv.mat
```

Or sth like this (for symmetry part):

```
for i=1:N                                                  
        for j=1:N                                              
            if i==j                                           
                A(:,:,p)=a(s)*eye(3);           %# 3x3 , a is a 1x200 constant array                        
                p=p+1;                          %# p is only a counter              
            elseif i>j          
                A(:,:,p)=... [just same as above]             
                p=p+1;          
            else
                A(:,:,p)=A(:,:,??);
                p=p+1;
            end                                             
        end                                                 
    end
```

I don't know is program clear?

Comment: A bigger [rv](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21031944/Stack/rv_bigger.mat)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJKJl.png

http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJKJl.png

http://i.stack.imgur.com/SOpya.png

http://i.imgur.com/podvp.png

Comment: Could you run the profiler to find out which part exactly requires the speedup?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience with finite element problems, I found that creating the large matrix `A` easily took as long, if not longer, than calculating the solution `x = A/b`.  Matlab does a good job with that matrix inverse.

In (old) FORTRAN creation of `A` is done with nested loops.  In Matlab this iteration is very slow.  One trick is to reverse the order of the nesting, so you iterate on small dimensions (the `3x3`), and use matrix operations on the large ones (`N`).  A further step is to do everything with matrix operations (on 4D arrays if needed), but that is harder to conceptualize.

I suspect your `A` matrix is sparse (lots of `eye` components).  In that case the Matlab sparse matrix operations can be your friend.  Basically you create 3 large vectors, `I`, `J`, `V`, where 2 identify the coordinates, and the third the (nonzero) value at each.  If a specific pair of coordinates is repeated, the corresponding values are added, which in some matrix definitions is convenient.  But that is more than I can explain here.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/30101/27783
takes a simple heat diffusion model, using loops and indexing, and speeds it up in several steps.  Simply vectorizing the inner loops helps a lot.  The best speed came generating a matrix using `eye` (or `diag`), and doing fast matrix multiplication (with `np.dot`).

Comment: If the goal is just solving linear equations, then indeed using `ldivide` or `rdivide` seems to be the way to go.