# Increase performance of Bayesian likelihood equation

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I need to calculate a Bayesian likelihood in its negative logarithmic form:

$$-\ln L = N\ln M -\sum\limits_{i=1}^{N} \ln\left\{P_i \sum\limits_{j=1}^M \frac{\exp\left[ -\frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{k=1}^D \frac{(f_{ik}-g_{jk})^2}{\sigma_{ik}^2 + \rho_{jk}^2}\right) \right]}{\prod_{k=1}^D \sqrt{\sigma_{ik}^2 + \rho_{jk}^2}} \right\}$$

where these $$P_i\;\;;\;\; f_{ik} \;\;;\;\; \sigma_{ik}^2\;\;;\;\; g_{jk} 
\;\;;\;\; \rho_{jk}^2$$ are all known floats. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np

# Define random data with correct shapes.
N, M = np.random.randint(10, 1000), np.random.randint(10, 1000)
D = np.random.randint(2, 5)
f_N, g_M = np.random.rand(N, D, 2), np.random.rand(M, D, 2)
P_i = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)

# N summatory.    
# Store here each 'i' element from the M summatory.
sum_Mi = []
for f_i in f_N:

    # M summatory.
    sum_M_j = 0.
    for g_j in g_M:

        # Obtain ijk element inside the M summatory
        D_sum, sigma_ijk = 0., 1.
        for k, f_ik in enumerate(f_i):
            # Where: f_ik[0] = \f_{ik}       ; g_j[k][0] = \g_{jk}
            # and:   f_ik[1] = \sigma_{ik}^2 ; g_j[k][1] = \rho_{jk}^2
            D_sum += np.square(f_ik[0] - g_j[k][0]) / (f_ik[1] + g_j[k][1])
            sigma_ijk = sigma_ijk * (f_ik[1] + g_j[k][1])

        sum_M_j += np.exp(-0.5 * D_sum) / np.sqrt(sigma_ijk)

    sum_Mi.append(sum_M_j)

sum_Mi_Pi = P_i * sum_Mi
# Remove 0. elements before applying the logarithm below.
sum_N = sum_Mi_Pi[sum_Mi_Pi != 0.]

# Final negative logarithmic likelihood
lik = len(f_N) * np.log(len(g_M)) - sum(np.log(sum_N))
print(lik)
```

I'm after an optimization done at the code level, ie: not using multi-threading.

I've tried `numpy` broadcasting on the inner loop

```
# Obtain ijk element inside the M summatory
D_sum = sum(np.square((f_i[:, 0] - g_j[:, 0])) / (f_i[:, 1] + g_j[:, 1]))
sigma_ijk = np.prod(f_i[:, 1] + g_j[:, 1])
```

but that actually *takes a longer time to complete* than using the `for` loop!

I also tried using the [logsumexp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.logsumexp.html) function from `scipy` combined with the broadcasted arrays:

```
# Store here each 'i' element from the M summatory.
sum_N = 0.
# N summatory.
for f_i in f_N:

    # M summatory.
    A, B = [], []
    for g_j in g_M:
        # Obtain ijk element inside the M summatory
        A.append(sum(
            np.square((f_i[:, 0] - g_j[:, 0])) / (f_i[:, 1] + g_j[:, 1])))
        B.append(np.prod(f_i[:, 1] + g_j[:, 1]))

    sum_N += logsumexp(-.5 * np.array(A), b=1. / np.sqrt(B))

# Final negative logarithmic likelihood
lik = len(f_N) * np.log(len(g_M)) - sum(np.log(P_i[P_i != 0.])) - sum_N
print(lik)
```

This resulted in a marginal improvement over just using broadcasting, but still slower than the original code.

Comment: There also seems to be a way to calculate the \$\sigma\$ from the \$f\$, which you do not show.

Comment: $f_{ik}$ is not equal to $f_{jk}$, the notation implies it but this is not true, Ill fix that. The $\sigma$s are completely independent of the $f$s. (Why is my LateX not rendering?)

Comment: You need to add a `\ ` in front of your `$`.

Comment: Thank you @Graipher, I've fixed the notation above. Please let mw know if something doesn't make sense to you. (testing \$\alpha\$)

Comment: Yes, my second comment. In your code you do `sigma_ijk = 1.; for k, f_ik in enumerate(f_i): sigma_ijk = sigma_ijk * (f_ik[1] + g_j[k][1])`. Does this mean that \$\sigma_{ik}\$ is a function of  \$f_{ik}\$ and \$g_{jk}\$?

Comment: Because you don't set them up in the data generation part. Also, what you call \$F\$ in the formula is `D` in your code.

Comment: No. \$\sigma_{ik}^2=\$`f_ik[1]` because that's where it is stored. It is not a function of \$f_{ik}=\$`f_ik[0]`. As I said, \$\sigma\$ and \$\rho\$ are completely independent of \$f\$ and \$g\$. I'll fix the `F` & `D` inconsistency.

Comment: Vectorizing the inner loop doesn't help because `D` is so small compared to `N` and `M`, e.g. 3 v 500 and 500.  It's just a few loops of a costly expression.

Comment: That makes sense @hpaulj. Any ideas on how I could vectorize the first two loops (which are the ones that take up most of the running time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much faster.  I added the `seed` to better compare results across runs.

```
import numpy as np

# Define random data with correct shapes.
np.random.seed(0)
N, M = np.random.randint(10, 1000), np.random.randint(10, 1000)
D = np.random.randint(2, 5)
f_N, g_M = np.random.rand(N, D, 2), np.random.rand(M, D, 2)
P_i = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N)

# replace loops with broadcasted array operation, followed by sums    
fgsum = f_N[:,None,:,1] + g_M[None,:,:,1]
fgdif = f_N[:,None,:,0] - g_M[None,:,:,0]
print(fgsum.shape)   # e.g. (694, 569, 3)

Dsum = (fgdif**2 / fgsum).sum(axis=-1)
sigma_ijk = np.prod(fgsum, axis=-1)
sum_M_j = np.exp(-0.5 * Dsum) / np.sqrt(sigma_ijk)
sum_Mi = np.sum(sum_M_j, axis=-1)

# as before
sum_Mi_Pi = P_i * sum_Mi
# Remove 0. elements before applying the logarithm below.
sum_N = sum_Mi_Pi[sum_Mi_Pi != 0.]

# Final negative logarithmic likelihood
lik = len(f_N) * np.log(len(g_M)) - sum(np.log(sum_N))
print(lik)
```

Comment: Excellent! This code is between 80-100 times faster in my machine, thank you very much hpaulj!

Comment: You can get another few percent faster by replacing `sum(np.log(sum_N))` with `np.log(sum_N).sum()` or `np.sum(np.log(sum_N))`.

Comment: okay ... nice that this is faster, but ... WHY???

Comment: Because it replaces Python loops with compiled `numpy` code.  Sorry.  I normally answer on SO where this kind of `numpy` 'vectorization' is an everyday question.

Comment: More about increasing performance with `numpy`: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17702/python-numpy-running-15x-slower-than-matlab-am-i-using-numpy-effeciently

Comment: Here's a [nice tutorial](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/broadcasting-arrays-in-numpy/) on `numpy`'s broadcasting.